# sp_invoke_external_rest_endpoint JSON string could not be parsed

Tags: azure-sql-database

Trying out HTTP GET from Azure SQL as per @mauridb's article https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sql/azure-sql-database-external-rest-endpoints-integration-public-preview/

Response: is 200, {"Success":true}
but Azure Data Studio shows:

```
    Msg 11558, Level 16, State 202, Procedure sp_invoke_external_rest_endpoint, Line 80
The @result JSON string could not be parsed. Please check the formatting of the JSON.
```

Sample code:

```
    DECLARE
        @url nvarchar(4000) = 'https://ifconfig.me/all.json'--put Azure Function Http GET endpoint
        ,@headers nvarchar(max) = N'{"x-functions-key":"keygoeshere"}'
        ,@payload nvarchar(max) = NULL
        ,@ret int
        ,@response nvarchar(max)
        ;

    exec @ret = sp_invoke_external_rest_endpoint 
        @url = @url,
        @method = 'GET',
        @headers = @headers,
        @payload = @payload,
        @response = @response output;
        
    select @ret as ReturnCode, @response as Response;
```

Comment: I guess start out by making the same call from Postman, go from there.

Answer (score 1):

On the @payload you need to specify the query. Specify the query in one line, because line breaks are not supported.

```
set @payload = N'{
"queries": [
{
"query": "Your query"
}
],
"serializerSettings": {
"includeNulls": true
}
}';
```

Download and install the latest Azure Data Studio or SQL Server Management Studio for the best user experience.

Answer (score 1):

On addition to @Alberto Morillo.

You try this below solution.

Even I got same error in my environment.

[image]

Here, the error is with parsing the json object.
That is something related to response in the function app where you are requesting.

[image]

Above are my function responses. Here you can see the return type is string. So that is the reason you are getting this error.
As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-invoke-external-rest-endpoint-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current&tabs=request-headers)  document the **result** should be in json format.

So modify your azure function app response as below.
Basically, as Json format.

[image]

Now executed in data studio got successful result.

[image]

Response:
[image]

Again, you can query the response as below.

```
SELECT  *  from  openjson(@response,'$.result')
```

[image]